# Log with --first-parent option

Tags: magit

How can I tell magit to use the `--first-parent` option?

I only want to see commits onto this branch, none from merged branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--first-parent` is included in current versions of Magit, but at a higher level than is shown by default in the transient menus.

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(transient)Enabling and Disabling Suffixes` for how to control this.

From the Magit Log menu you can either:

- Change the default level for that menu using `C-x l C-x l` to make all those hidden options visible.
- Change the level of `--first-parent` specifically with `C-x l =p`, to include it at your current level.

Alternatively, you can customize `transient-default-level`.

Comment: Looks like `C-x l` is bound to `count-lines-page`. Using `C-h k`: "`C-x l` runs the command  count-lines-page (found in global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘page.el’."

Comment: Did you type it with the magit log transient menu open?  If so, which version of Magit are you using?

Comment: Yup, that was my problem! I was trying it from the log buffer, not the transient menu. Marking as solution.